# Dialog with list view and message

Tags: android, listview, dialog, android-alertdialog

I need to create dialog with both ListView and message, however according to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10948 it is not possible with standard AlertDialog. So I've decided to create custom view with text and listview, and attach it to dialog.

However, my list view is drawn empty. Here is java code:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Hello, title!");

    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View content = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

    ListView lv = (ListView) content.findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, ITEMS));
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    builder.setView(content).setPositiveButton("OK", this).setNegativeButton("Cancel", this);

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Also I have:

```
    final String[] ITEMS = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
```

and here is dialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, text!" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list"
    ></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is result: [image: dialog_with_empty_list_view]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `android:orientation="vertical"` in linearlayout.

Your xml will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, text!" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list"

    ></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

set orientation is vertical like

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

     <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Hello, text!" />

     <ListView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/list"
     ></ListView>

     </LinearLayout>
```

in your layout