# ListView with Custom dialog box

Tags: android, listview, customdialog

I have written the code in which I am getting the result from database which I am binding to listview successfully.But Now I want that listview in Custom dialog format.Means List data should come in dialog.How to attach the listdata to custom dialog box ?

```
final Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllRecords();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                RecordsDbAdapter.KEY_NAME,
                RecordsDbAdapter.KEY_BIRTHDAY,

        };
        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.name,
                R.id.birthdate,
        };
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.row,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList

Comment: I have seen that But I am not able to understand how to add my listview data to custom Dialogbox.Means I am getting data in ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);how to attach it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dialog with list view and message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423706/dialog-with-list-view-and-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind an adapter to an `AlertDialog`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setAdapter(dataAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        // Stuff that happens when an item is clicked
    }
});
builder.show();
```

Comment: I included sample code already. That shows you how to implement it.

Comment: yes its working,can we implement the checkbox there ? and to get the checked items from it ?

Comment: Sure you can add whatever you want. You supply the layout when you create the `SimpleCursorAdapter`, so it's up to you what you want to include and how to manage it.

Comment: I have added the checkbox in my row,xnk.Please help me how to get the checked Items from it.